# How to find a post when all you know is the post_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have a simple app for submitting data and after submission I have a share option.
When a user actually shares something he is redirected by Facebook to a specified URI.

Facebook also provides the post_id by appending it to the URI (like http://my-redirected-URL?post_id=100001175803635_321643121201516).

So, without asking anything from the user, I can tell if he shared information or not, and I have his post_id (but not his user_id or name).

But how can I see what he actually wrote? I have his post_id. Where can I look?
I've tried the open graph but with no luck.
I thought this was an answer: [what is the url to a facebook open graph post id?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4729477/what-is-the-url-to-a-facebook-open-graph-post-id), also no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have user `access_token` for user who shared the content you can issue `GET` request to Graph API to get the data by post id (`100001175803635_321643121201516` for example):

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Response is the [`Post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object which will have non empty `message` property if user added some text to shared content...